# I want a secure UITextField that can use an international keyboard

Tags: iphone, security, sdk, keyboard, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why can't I use secureTextEntry with a UTF-8 keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944769/why-cant-i-use-securetextentry-with-a-utf-8-keyboard)

Apparently secureTextEntry textfields only accepts english characters. I turned on a couple of keyboards on my device and only those like English and French with ABC characters were available (arabic, chinese, korean, were not). When I make the text insecure it they do work.

Can anyone help me with a workaround?